# PHP ifelse display white screen of death

Tags: php

My code doesnt work properly and it does now shows any error or any clue, what am I missing here ? any hints ? TIA

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_session_organizer']))
  { ?>
      <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
  <?php } ?>
   <?php
    elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
    {
    ?>
    <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
  <?php }else{ ?>
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#organizer" class="smoothScroll">ORGANIZE TRIPS</a></li>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What was the output? Blank?

Comment: I would recommend you to minimize the usage of <?php and ?>. It maybe wouldn't directly fix your problem, but it really unclutters your code and makes it easier to read.

Comment: @anant done already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One unnecessary `<?php` and `else if` is in wrong way, do like below:-

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_session_organizer'])){ ?>
    <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
<?php } elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])){?>
    <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
<?php }else{ ?>
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#organizer" class="smoothScroll">ORGANIZE TRIPS</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Note:-

Always add

***`error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);`***

on top of your each `php` page to prevent yourself from a situation like:-***"White Screen Of Death"***

(It will on the error reporting setting for all type of errors and every error will displayed on the page if any occur).

Thanks

Comment: @MartneyAcha  glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, your else if is wrong ?> is a close tag and then the compiler dont understand the elseif, better this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_session_organizer']))
                { ?>
                    <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
                <?php }elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
                {
                ?>
                <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
                <?php }else{ ?>
                    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#organizer" class="smoothScroll">ORGANIZE TRIPS</a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to read and to debug:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_session_organizer'])) : ?>
<li>
    <a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a>
</li>
<?php elseif (isset($_SESSION['user_session'])) : ?>
<li>
    <a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a>
</li>
<?php else : ?>
<li>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#organizer" class="smoothScroll">ORGANIZE TRIPS</a>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Check about [control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Answer (score 1):

try this, its neat and simple code.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_session_organizer'])): ?>
     <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
<?php elseif (isset($_SESSION['user_session'])): ?>
    <li><a href="triplist.php" class="smoothScroll">VIEW TRIPS</a></li>
<?php else: ?>
    <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#organizer" class="smoothScroll">ORGANIZE TRIPS</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```